# cucumber, protractor test passed even if it is not correct

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, cucumber

I'm using protractor with cucumber (and cucumber reports) to test my app but I have an issue when I launch it. I check if a string is equal to another string, but is not and i know it. The fact is that after test launch the test passed but returns me an exeption.

The console returns this:

```
[15:56:41] E/launcher - expected 'Login Failed: This value is not existing'
                          to equal 'Values are incorrect'
[15:56:41] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected 'Login Failed: This value is not existing'
                          to equal 'Values are incorrect'
```

My stepdefinitions.js:

```
Then('I see the alert "Values are incorrect" for the contents which does not match the proper data',
    function (next) {

    let failed_msg = element(by.css('.faild-message'));
    failed_msg.getText().then(function(text){
        console.log('MY ALERT MESSAGE FOR SCENARIO EIGHT IS: ',text);
        expect(text.should.be.equal("Values are incorrect"));  
        next();
    });
});
```

The output for console.log is:

```
MY ALERT MESSAGE FOR SCENARIO EIGHT IS:  Login Failed: This value is not existing
```

Can someone help me?

PS: Cucumber reports don't show anything about this exception and told me that every tests are passed. Why? The strings are not equal and console told me that too. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you add `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in protractor conf.js?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a return or a callback out of this block (I prefer returns over callbacks myself):

```
Then('I see the alert "Values are incorrect" for the contents which does not match the proper data', function (next) {
    let failed_msg = element(by.css('.faild-message'));
    return failed_msg.getText().then(function(text){
        console.log('MY ALERT MESSAGE FOR SCENARIO EIGHT IS: ',text);
        expect(text.should.be.equal("Values are incorrect"));  
        return next();
    });
});
```

Because you are working within a promise and sending out the callback, this needs to be returned upwards so that the step doesn't pass before the code within is run.

Comment: Hi Kyle, thank you for your reply. I tried with your solution and correctly it fails on console, but in the report of cucumber every step is passed :/

Comment: Perhaps foregoing the next() and returning on the expect will work? It seems really odd

Comment: No, is the same :/

Comment: My thought process on that was that it would return the failing state of the expect statement instead of returning the callback early (if it did). I don’t know, this is a really odd situation.

Comment: I think is a configuration problem, but i don't know what is the problem